# when can we make Function from its partial derivatives?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

Given $(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y},\frac{\partial f}{\partial z})$.It is also known that all three are polynomial in x,y,z.I want a criteria when there exist a possible $f$.

Comment: Do you *know* that those three are $(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y},\frac{\partial f}{\partial z})$ or they are simply three functions and you want to *find out* if it is possible to write as a gradient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\nabla f = \langle f_x, f_y, f_z \rangle$ is the gradient of $f$.

Given $F = \langle P,Q,R \rangle$, if there is an $f$ such that $\nabla f = F$, we say that $F$ is a gradient vector field. Under mild assumptions this is equivalent to saying $F$ is a conservative vector field (its line integrals have a path independence property).

Now suppose that $f$ has continuous second partials (to make sure Clairaut's theorem holds). Then $\nabla \times \nabla f = {\bf 0}$ (the curl of the gradient is zero).

Thus if the component functions of $F = \langle P,Q,R \rangle$ have continuous partials, we must have that $\nabla \times F = {\bf 0}$ if $F$ has any hope of being conservative.

It turns out that the converse is true as long as $\nabla \times F = {\bf 0}$ on a "simply connected" region (meaning one piece and no "1-dimensional holes"). This follows from Stokes' theorem.

[Wikipedia has more details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field).

In summary, for reasonably "nice" (i.e. they have sufficiently many continuous partials) functions $P$, $Q$, and $R$ defined on a simply connected region we have that $P=f_x$, $Q=f_y$, $R=f_z$ for some function $f$ if and only if $\nabla \times F = {\bf 0}$ where $F = \langle P,Q,R \rangle$.

Answer (score 2):

Given $\bigtriangledown f$ = $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ = $(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y},\frac{\partial f}{\partial z})$

then $\cfrac{\partial a_1^2}{\partial y \partial z} = \cfrac{\partial a_2^2}{\partial x \partial z} = \cfrac{\partial a_3^2}{\partial x \partial y}$ is a necessary condition for a continuous function $f$ to exist

---

This necessary condition comes from assuming that $f$ is differentialble, then switching the order of differentiation doesn't change the value . so $\cfrac{\partial f^3}{\partial x \partial y \partial z} = \cfrac{\partial f^3}{\partial y \partial x \partial z } = \cfrac{\partial f^3}{\partial z \partial y \partial x }$

Since $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ = $(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y},\frac{\partial f}{\partial z})$, you can see how I got the required necessary condition

Comment: can you please give some reference about this !